# aggregate function error in case expression

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this query

```
SELECT mylearning.Employee_Id,
 case 
        when max(case when not mylearning.CourseStatusTXT = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then '2018 Complete'
        when max(case when mylearning.CourseStatusTXT in ('Started', 'Not Started') then 1 else 0 end) = 1 then '2018 Not Complete'
  end as Completion_Status
FROM  Analytics.myLearning_Completions as mylearning inner join Analytics.Workday WD on mylearning.Employee_ID = WD.Employee_ID
```

And I want to add a condition to the first when statement to make it like this

```
 when max(case when not mylearning.CourseStatusTXT = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 
             and WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date like '2019% '
            and mylearning.CourseTimeCompletedH < cast (WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date as date format 'YYYY/MM/DD') +7
             then '2018 Complete'
```

but I keep getting this error

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3504 : HY000] Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.069
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your 1st Select is already invalid due to the missing `group by mylearning.Employee_Id`. You probably need to add aggregate functions, too, e.g. `and MAX(WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date) like '2019% '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a couple others mentioned, you are trying to mix grouped data with non-aggregated data in your calculation, which is why you're getting the `3504` error.  You need to either include the referenced columns in your `GROUP BY` or include them inside an aggregate function (i.e. MAX).

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're after, but hopefully it can help you along.

```sql
SELECT 
  mylearning.Employee_Id,
  CASE
    WHEN 
      MAX(CASE WHEN NOT mylearning.CourseStatusTXT = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
      WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date like '2019% ' AND
      -- Check if most recently completed course is before Hire (Date + 1 week)
      MAX(mylearning.CourseTimeCompletedH) < 
      CAST(WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD') + 7 
    THEN '2018 Complete' -- No incomplete learnings
    WHEN MAX(
      CASE WHEN mylearning.CourseStatusTXT IN ('Started', 'Not Started') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) = 1 THEN '2018 Not Complete' -- Started / Not Started learnings exist
  END AS Completion_Status
FROM Analytics.myLearning_Completions as mylearning  -- Get learning info
INNER JOIN Analytics.Workday WD on mylearning.Employee_ID = WD.Employee_ID -- Employee info
GROUP BY mylearning.Employee_Id, WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date
```

This will give you a summary per employee, with a couple assumptions:

1. Assuming `employee_ID` value in `Analytics.Workday` is a unique value (one-to-one join), to use `WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date` in your comparisons, you just need to include it in the `GROUP BY`.
2. Assuming you have multiple courses per `employee_Id`, in order to use `mylearning.CourseTimeCompletedH` in your comparisons, you'd need to wrap that in an aggregate like `MAX`.

The caveat here is that the query will check if the most recently completed course per employee is before the "hire_date" expression, so I'm not sure if that's what you're after.

Give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are mixing detail row by row information in the same query as group or aggregated data.  Aggregated data will output a single value for all the rows unless you have a group by clause.  If you have a group by clause then it will output a single value for each group.  When you are grouping you can also include any values that are in the group by clause since they will be unique for the group.

if you want this data for each employee, then you could group by employee_id.  Any other data would need to also be an aggregate like Max(Adjusted_Hire_Date)

Comment: could you please add the code you are proposing to increase the quality of your answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT 
  mylearning.employee_id
  , case 
    when CourseStatusTXT = 'Completed' and WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date like '2019%' 
      and mylearning.CourseTimeCompletedH < cast (WD.Adjusted_Hire_Date as date format 'YYYY/MM/DD') +7
    then '2018 Complete'
    else '2018 Not Complete'
  end CompletionStatus
FROM  myLearning_Completions mylearning, Workday WD 
WHERE mylearning.employee_id = WD.employee_id
```